# AJAX file upload reloading application

Tags: ajax, scala, file-upload, lift

I have the following snippet

```
class PresentationUpload {

    def uploadForm(form:NodeSeq) : NodeSeq = {

        var fileHolder: Box[FileParamHolder] = Empty

        def handleFile() = {

            fileHolder.map { holder =>

                val filePath = "src/main/webapp/files"
                val oFile = new File(filePath, holder.fileName)

                val output = new FileOutputStream(oFile)
                output.write(holder.file)
                output.close()

            } openOr {

                // Do something

            }


        }

        val bindForm = "type=file" #> fileUpload((fph) => fileHolder = Full(fph)) &
                       "type=submit" #> ajaxSubmit("Submit", handleFile _)

        ajaxForm(bindForm(form))

    }

}
```

The file uploads correctly but then reloads the application, is this the correct way to handle ajax uploads or is there another method I should be using?

Thanks for any help, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I've configured the lift project (normally "project/build/LiftProject.scala") to not reload after changes to the files directory, problem solved :)

```
override def scanDirectories = ( 

    temporaryWarPath / "WEB-INF" * ("classes" | "lib") 

).get.toSeq
```